# Counting Sundays in c++;

Tags: c++

You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

> 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.  Thirty days has September, April, June and November.  All the rest have thirty-one, Saving February alone, Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.  And on leap years, twenty-nine. A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
>   How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

I don't seem to get the right answer or find the bug. I get the answer 85.

```
int main(){
    int month[12]={31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int j=0;
    int i= 1901;
    int day=1;
    int sunday=0;

    for(i=1901;i<2001;i++) {

        if( i % 4==0 ){
             month[1]=29;
        }
        else {
            month[1]=28;
        }

        for (j=0;j<12;j++){

            if (day % 7 ==0){
                sunday++;
            }
            day+=month[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout<< sunday<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The initial values appear to encode Jan 1 1901 = Monday, but the instructions were Jan 1 1900 = Monday.

Comment: @Bathsheba Silly me.  I deleted my comment.

Comment: You're incrementing `j` twice in the loop. (And your newline key seems to get stuck often.)

Comment: Yeah thanks, the problem was actually incrementing j twice....

Answer (score 4):

Bisides what [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba) already pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418874/4342498) You are also skipping every other month.  In your for loop you increment `j` at the end of the loop and then `j` will get incremented again at the start of the next loop.

```
for (j=0;j<12;j++){
    if (day % 7 ==0){
        sunday++;

    }
    day+=month[j];
    j++;<--------------get rid of this
}
```

Comment: Nicked your `++j` so need to upvote on those grounds.

Comment: @Bathsheba Don't forget to add attribution ;) JK.  Your answer looks good  and I upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the normal definition of the 20th century is from 1-Jan-1900 to 31-Dec-1999, consider changing the loop to `for (i = 1900; i < 2000; ++i)`.

If you need the range to be from 1-Jan-1901 to 31-Dec-2000 then note that 1-Jan-
1901 was a Tuesday and so the starting value of `day` needs to be 2.

You also have a spurious `j++;` in your month iteration (acknowledge @NathanOliver)

Other than that, the algorithm looks fine. Although I don't like the continuous writing to `month`.

Comment: I changed the initial value of the year to 1900, so the day is 1 instead. But i still don't get the right answer.

Comment: Wikipedia says that 20th century [started on 1-Jan-1901](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_century). People forget that there was no year 0. There was year 1, and year before that was 1 BC.

Comment: I remember this debate at the start of the 21st century. But I think it was an excuse for certain folk to party hard on 31-Dec-2000.

Comment: Yeah i know i fixed that bug too.